# How can I check if one role is in front of another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a Discord Bot that change the User Nickname. The Bot is working, but when i give me the role Co-Owner hes renaming me to [Co-Owner] User. But i already have the role Owner. I like when a certain role is in front of another that he doesn't change my nickname. How can i do that?

Thats my Code right now:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        new_role = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
        if new_role.name in ('Twitch VIP'):
            await after.edit(nick=f"[VIP] {after.name}")
        elif new_role.name in ('Co-Owner'):
            await after.edit(nick=f"[Co-Owner] {after.name}")
        elif new_role.name in ('Owner '):
            await after.edit(nick=f"[Owner] {after.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Owner and Co-Owner have the same word in it.

Comment: No im checking the complete String. With other roles the same issues are happening